# Javascript output in the source files?

Tags: php, javascript

Before I can explain this please view this URL in Google chrome and view the page source:
http://goo.gl/Ds9oOz

in the page source you will see this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--


echo 'setClockMulti("CDT", 1)';



//-->
</script>
```

This will show the time zone of CHICAGO on the page when viewed on a browser.

what I am trying to achieve is to be able to view the time zone of CHICAGO in the source files as well!

I know javascript is a client side by the way so save your breath and PHP is a server side.

can someone please give me some sort of example or tutorial to achive what i am trying to do?

and I don't mind using AJAX.. i Just need some sort of clear instructions.

Comment: If you want to change the source code, then you have to change it before it gets to the browser. Client side JavaScript (ajax included) can't help you.

Comment: Just to let you know, even if you modify the source of a document using javascript it wont show up in the view source of your browser unless you have some developer extension that allows you to view generated source

Comment: If you want clear instructions, you probably need a clear question.  What precisely do you want to do?

Comment: are you mixing php and javascript?

Comment: The server side is what generates the source, so forget Javascript.

Comment: Is `setClockMulti()` a PHP function or a JS function? If the above is visible in the page source as viewed from the browser then it will _not_ show the actual time in Chicago in the browser because that's not valid JS.

Comment: @nnnnnn, setClockMulti is a javascript function.

Comment: @GolezTrol, that is very helpful. not.

Comment: It's not possible to do what you're trying to do. When you use your browser's "View Page Source" option it shows you the page source as received from the web server when the page first loaded. By definition this will not include anything calculated in client-side JavaScript. I can't think of a good reason why you'd even want to do this - can you explain _why_ you are trying to do this?

Comment: @nnnnnn, it is not my request. a client of mine asked me as he thinks displaying the time in the source files will help them for their SEO process.

Comment: You'll have to explain to the client that that is not how web browsers work. But you _can_ offer the client an alternative option: calculate those times server-side and _then_ they'd be output in the original source.

Comment: @nnnnnn, any examples of on how to calculate time zones server side?

Comment: @JessyJordan Not helpful? Seldom was so much truth told in such a short sentence!. ;-)  But without kidding, I wrote an answer that hopefully puts things better in perspective than a short comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible in Javascript.

If you want to have the content in the source for SEO purposes, you need to render it server side. So if the site is built on PHP and Javascript, build it in PHP. 
You *can* do it in Javascript if you have server side Javascript running (e.g. Node.js), but I'm guessing this is not the case.

The client side Javascript runs in the browser and only when the document is loaded. Ajax is a Javascript technique to do an extra request in the background to get extra content. This won't help you in this situation, because search engines won't run this Javascript, so they won't have the dynamically loaded content.

If you want to know what Google indexes, disable Javascript in your browser and see what is left of your page. That is what search engines see, nothing else.

If that means you have to translate `setClockMulti` to PHP, so be it. It's probably easier than installing Node.js. If you need help translating it, I guess you can ask a new question describing your exact problems.

Comment: Actually [you can get Google to index Ajax content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en). But it does involve setting the page up the way Google wants you to.

Comment: @nnnnnn Interesting! Thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--


<?php echo setClockMulti("CDT", 1); ?>



//-->
</script>
```

Comment: if setClockMulti is a PHP function it would. :)

Comment: I can only assume it is defined somewhere :)

Comment: that is what i already have. no the setClockMulti is a javascript function.

Comment: Ah well forget this idea then!